# Properties of a digit sum and modulo

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, computer-science, computational-complexity

I am trying to solve a computational problem. The problem is like this;

Let me define a number and show it as $s(n)$ that represents the smallest number, that has a digit sum of $n$. So $s(10) = 19 (1+9=10)$, $s(11) = 29$, $s(18) = 99$, $s(23) = 599$ etc.

Now I need to calculate the $s(n)$ for $n \geq 10^8$.
In this case, one of the problems is storage. For instance,

$s(1000) =1999999999
99999999999999999999999
9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
999999999999999999999999999999999999$

So It's hard for me to calculate $s(10^8)$ computationally, and the computer could not handle such large values. For this reason I want to only store the $k$, where $k = s(n)\mod(h)$. The main problem is that since $s(10^8)$ is so large, the computer cannot store it properly to calculate its $\mod (h)$ to find $k$.

I believe that in order to solve this problem we need some sort of relation between $s(n)$ values (i.e $s(n)$ and $s(n-1)$ etc.) or between $s(n)$ and $n$.

So that we can calculate its mod before storing that number. For instance (imagine that) if we had known $s(n-2) \mod (h)$ and $s(n-1) \mod (h)$, it would be much easier to calculate $s(n) \mod(h)$. So simply I need some realation between $s(n)$ values...Any ideas ?

The pattern that I have noticed between $n$ and $s(n)$ is something like this

`s(n) = int(str(n % 9) + '9' * (n // 9))` for $n \geq 9$

(In python)

but this is not useful for $n \geq 10^6$ which is clear from the example I am given above. I need to insert mod in some places so that I can go up to $n \approx 10^8$ and more

Comment: Didn't the examples you computed suggest a simple pattern?  Also, your value for $s(100)$ is far too high.

Comment: @lulu sorry my mistake it should be $1000$. Yes I noticed a patter but thats not useful

Comment: You'd better find the pattern and *not* store the number; only provide a compressed form.

Comment: This kind of problems are sometimes programming competitions and usually we do not discuss solutions on this site. In any case, we would prefer that you give the source of the problem.

Comment: Please edit your post to describe the pattern and to explain why you think it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is essentially to put as many $9$s as possible on the right, and any remainder on the left.

- So if $f(n)=\lfloor n/9 \rfloor$ then you have $f(n)$ $9$s on the right, which is $10^{f(n)} -1$
- plus $n-9f(n)$ on the left, corresponding to $(n-9f(n)) \times  10^{f(n)}$
- making a total of $(n-9f(n)+1) \times  10^{f(n)}-1$,  or if you prefer $$s(n) =(n-9\lfloor n/9 \rfloor+1) \times  10^{\lfloor n/9 \rfloor}-1$$

Since powers of $10$ are $1$ more than a multiple of $9$, giving you $1$ on the left, you can say for example that $$s(10^{18}) = 2 \times 10^{(10^{18}-1)/9}-1$$

For modulo $p$ powers when $p$ is prime, you can use Fermat's little theorem to speed up calculations

Comment: is $f(n)$ a floor function ?

Comment: It is the floor of $n/9$

Answer (score 0):

The key observations that should allow you to accomplish your task are:

- A string of $k$ $9$s in a row is equal to the number $10^k-1$. Therefore a digit $d$ followed by a string of $k$ $9$s is equal to $(d+1)10^k-1$.
- [Modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) will allow you to compute $10^k\pmod h$ extremely quickly, without storing any numbers larger than $\max\{h,k\}$.

Comment: Can you give example. I could nt follow what is $k$ and what is $d$ in your example ?